# nested selectbox - set second jquery dropdown when first is changed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I am trying to create a dynamic set of dropdown boxes, using jQuery/AJAX and PHP/MySQL. The first dropdown box will be populated when the page loads based on values from a database. The second dropdown box should display a set of values based on the selection from the first dropdown box.

I used Chosen plugin in order to have search option.

My problem is: when I select the first selectbox, nothing is shown in the second selectbox. when I remove  `class="chosen-select"`from the Html, it works correctly!

I need the search in selectbox. So, what should I do?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.chosen-select').chosen({ 
         no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });  
$('#search1').on('change', function (){
$('#search2').html("<option value=''>Select</option>");// add this on each call then add the options when data receives from the request
    $.getJSON('select.php', {id: $(this).val()}, function(data){
        var options = '';
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['Date'] + '</option>';
        }
        $('#search2').html(options);
        //$('.chosen-select').chosen();
    });
});
});
</script>
```

This is the second select:

```
<select  id="search2" name="search" type="text" data-placeholder="Choose an Option..."     style="width:370px;" class="chosen-select" onChange="drawChart(this.value);">
<option value=""></option> 
</select>
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.chosen-select').chosen({
         no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
    });  
$('select#search1').on('change', function (){
    $('select#search2').html("<option value=''>Select the Option..</option>");// add this on each call then add the options when data receives from the request
    $.getJSON('select.php', {id: $(this).val()}, function(data){
        $('select#search2').empty(); 

        var options = '<option value="0">Select the Option..</option>';
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            options += '<option value="' + data[x]['id'] + '">' + data[x]['Date'] + '</option>';
        }
        $('select#search2').chosen();
        $('select#search2').html(options);
        $("#search2").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
});
});
</script>
```